# Convert MSP432 freeRTOS demo project to Fresh empty Project

Tags: rtos, freertos, msp432

I recently started to learn RTOS. I need help to modify MSP432 freeRTOS demo project to a fresh Project or Create a new freeRTOS project for MSP432. I use Code compiler studio from Texas Instrument. I searched all over the web, but no luck.

Comment: I feel your pain. The make magic used makes it amazingly hard to comprehend all moving parts of these projects. I tried to move up from Arduino to bear C + FreeRTOS but I guess I will stick to Arduino for now...

Answer (score 1):

As replied on the FreeRTOS forum too:

If you really must create a project from scratch then the following 
links might help, but it is really best to adapt an existing project 
that start a new one:
http://www.freertos.org/Creating-a-new-FreeRTOS-project.html
http://www.freertos.org/porting-a-freertos-demo-to-different-hardware.html